# how to increase dynamically load on jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to increase the load of JMeter like first i will pass the load at 5tps then after some time 10tps then after some time 15tps so on how can I do this in dynamically.
any guidance or help would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) where you can specify the desired workload pattern in terms of "requests per second"

Here is example setup which:

- holds the load at 5 requests per second for 60 minutes
- then holds the load at 10 requests per second for another 60 minutes
- then holds the load at 15 requests per second for another 60 seconds
- then ramps-down the load back

[image]

Just make sure to provide enough threads (virtual users) so JMeter would be able to conduct the required amount of requests per second, it makes sense to consider using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) for this and connect it to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function)

More information: [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options for dynamic throughput controlling

1. **Pre-configured**

[Throughput shaping timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer Feedback Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function)

2. **Set at Runtime**
   [Use Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) to set the dynamic throughput values in [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html?#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

[This article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2020/10/controlling-the-throughput-in-jmeter/) (which has a video) will have more details.

[image]

[image]